# Why does my multithread application hang?

Tags: c++, multithreading, mfc

I have code that creates and starts a thread:

```
CWinThread *m_pThread;
m_pThread = AfxBeginThread(StartThread, m_pObj, THREAD_PRIORITY_NORMAL, CREATE_SUSPENDED, 0);
m_pThread->m_bAutoDelete = FALSE;
m_pThread->ResumeThread();
```

This is my function. It waits to finish this thread because I want start new thread:

```
void Some()
{
  m_pObj->bRefresh = true;
  DWORD dw = ::WaitForSingleObject(m_pThread->m_hThread, INFINITE);//hangs and doesn't move anywhere
}
```

But returning from my thread is fine.

Please help me find what I did wrong?

```
UINT StartThread(LPVOID lpParam)
{
Obj *pObj = (Obj*)lpParam;
while(!pObj->Refresh)
{}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: It sounds like the child thread is never exiting. Does it do something that is waiting on the main thread? It would be helpful to see what `StartThread()` is doing to get an idea of what could be causing it to never exit.

Comment: Verify that the thread finishes. Verify that the thread handle is correct. Don't assume, but be sure.

Comment: The code you show looks OK. The problem must be elsewhere.

Comment: Actually I checked my thread has exited fine

Comment: Are you calling your WaitForSingleObject after the thread has already ended. Its been quite some time since I used that. I can not remember if that works.

Comment: I have a lot of logic inside this loop!
And if I couldn't exit at time from thread I got hangs both threads

Comment: Are you sure that your m_pThread is valid and is the thread you created when you call Some()?

Comment: Yes. I'm sure. But m_hThread handle has every time same address
for each call

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is too localized to be generally useful to other users.

Comment: `while(!pObj->Refresh) {}` is an infinite loop.  If you meant to call a member function named `Refresh`, then you need more parentheses:  `while (!pObj->Refresh()) {}`.  I did not put this into an answer because this question should be closed as "too localized".

Comment: Just to confirm: `CWinThread *m_pThread;` variable: is it global? Is it defined only once, or again the second time, right before your AfxBeginThread?

Comment: Has `bRefresh` in `m_pObj` been declared as `volatile`?

Comment: bRefresh is not volatile. The main idea is my loop works while bRefresh false, when I change bRefresh to true the loop is closed and thread too.

Comment: `bRefresh` has to be `volatile` or the compiler might optimize the check into in front of the loop.

Answer (score 0):

The main problem was that I couldn't return from loop, and that's why my thread hangs
thanks a lot for replaying